# How to fix Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: error

Tags: java, string, numbers

I'm writing a program that will find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product.

```
public class day1m {

public static void main(String[] args)
```

{

```
    int i=0; long temp=1;
    String n= "7316717653133062491922511967442657474235534919493496983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843858615607891129494954595017379583319528532088055111254069874715852386305071569329096329522744304355766896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113622298934233803081353362766142828064444866452387493035890729629049156044077239071381051585930796086670172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776657273330010533678812202354218097512545405947522435258490771167055601360483958644670632441572215539753697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482839722413756570560574902614079729686524145351004748216637048440319989000889524345065854122758866688116427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586178664583591245665294765456828489128831426076900422421902267105562632111110937054421750694165896040807198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188845801561660979191338754992005240636899125607176060588611646710940507754100225698315520005593572972571636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450";
    while(i<1000)
    {
        String sub13= n.substring(0, 13);
        long pro=1;
        for(int j=0;j<13;j++)
        {
            char numletter=sub13.charAt(j);
            int num=Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(numletter)); 
            pro=pro*num;
        }
        if(pro>temp)
        {
            temp=pro;
        }
        
        n=n.substring(1);
        i++;
        
    }
    System.out.println(temp);
}
```

}

however, i keep getting this error:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 13
at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1963)
at myfirstproject.day1m.main(day1m.java:14)

Why am i getting this error? how do i fix it?

Comment: At some point, your string `n`'s length is smaller than 13.

Comment: how do i fix it tho?

Comment: ... don't let the length of `n` go below 13

Answer (score 0):

Change the while condition to `while(i<1000 && n.length() >= 13)` to make sure you have enough characters for `String sub13= n.substring(0, 13);`